# Ruby object references

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, object, reference

I came across a snippet of code in Ruby that confused me. Boiling it down to a simple example below to illustrate. Why is it that sArr does not have its contents automatically updated in the first case but it happens in the second case? The snippets are short and self explanatory with three returns separating the two scenarios.

```
2.0.0-p598 :068 > str = "Hello"
=> "Hello" 
2.0.0-p598 :069 > sArr = [str]
=> ["Hello"] 
2.0.0-p598 :070 > str = str.upcase
=> "HELLO" 
2.0.0-p598 :071 > str
=> "HELLO" 
2.0.0-p598 :072 > sArr
=> ["Hello"]  # Why is this not ["HELLO"] like in the sequence below?
2.0.0-p598 :073 > 
2.0.0-p598 :074 >   
2.0.0-p598 :075 >   
2.0.0-p598 :076 >   str = "Hello"
=> "Hello" 
2.0.0-p598 :077 > sArr = [str]
=> ["Hello"] 
2.0.0-p598 :078 > str.upcase!
=> "HELLO" 
2.0.0-p598 :079 > sArr
=> ["HELLO"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a new String instance is created with `str = str.upcase` but not `str.upcase!`:

```
str = "Hello"
str.object_id
# => 70132476337960 
str = str.upcase
# => "HELLO" 
str.object_id
# => 70132476374360 (new instance)

str = "Hello"
str.object_id
# => 70132476415240 
str.upcase!
# => "HELLO" 
str.object_id
# => 70132476415240 (same instance)
```

`sArr` is unaffected by `str = str.upcase` since it is holding a reference to the initial `"Hello"`. Assigning to `str` doesn't change the object in `sArr` any more than if you did `str = 'World'`. In contrast, `str.upcase!` modifies the instance held by `sArr`.